# Get PDF pages which contain images

Tags: python, bash, pdf

I'm searching for a programmatical solution to find all those page (their pagenumber for example) which contain at least one image. I do NOT need the images as themselves, I only need the page numbers. A shell-scripting solution or python solution is prefered, but everything which helps to complete this task is ok.

Background: I'm OCRing the PDF's and I need to know on which pages it makes sense to run an OCR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use `pdfimages`, a utility from the `poppler-utils` package. It can output some information on the images stored in the pdf:

```
$ pdfimages -list file.pdf
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID
---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image     200   197  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no         7  0
```

The page numbers are of-by-one (counting from 1), `identify` (from the `ImageMagik` package) can show you all the page numbers:

```
$ identify -format '%p ' file
0 1 2 3
```

One can see from these two commands, that pages 2,3,4 do not contain images whereas page 1 does.